# MySQL: Algebra in Union operation

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I have below query:

```
select entity_id from table1 exc 
UNION 
select entity_id from tabl2 inc
```

On execution, I got `24419` rows.

When I execute `select entity_id from table1 exc` I got `16235` rows and on the execution of `select entity_id from tabl2 inc` I got `35943` rows.

Below is the explain result of above query:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: exc
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: IDX_ENTITY_ID
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 15603
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: UNION
        table: inc
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: IDX_ENTITY_ID
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 32697
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: NULL
  select_type: UNION RESULT
        table: <union1,2>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: NULL
        Extra:
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table structure of table1

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rule_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`,`rule_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `idx_rule_id_jos_tag_rules_content_exclude` (`rule_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Table structure of table2

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rule_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`,`rule_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `idx_rule_id_jos_tag_rules_content_include` (`rule_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

If we see on algebric calculation behind Union operation then it should be max(No(a)+no(b)).
Now, I am unable to understand behind above result. How MySQL perform Union operation?

Comment: What is the question? Why you get `24419` and not  `16235+35943` rows in the result?

Comment: UNION eliminates the duplicates,use UNION ALL to include them.

Comment: @ypercube: yes, this is my question.

Answer (score 1):

union returns distinct results.
try UNION ALL

select entity_id from table1 exc 
UNION ALL
select entity_id from tabl2 inc

Comment: Union in MySQL different than Union in Set theory of Math?